# hover child element only

Tags: jquery

I have p tags with images in them, and I want the user to be able to hover the image tag only. Currently, when the user hovers the image, it triggers the paragraph `mouseenter` and the image `mouseenter` never fires.

```
<p>Some text.. <img src="(URL)" /></p>
```

I am currently using mouseenter.

```
    // Hover over a paragraph
    $("article p").mouseenter(function () {
        window.console.log("paragraph trigger");
        self.showControls(this, "p");
    });

    // Hover over an image in a paragraph
    $("article p img").mouseenter(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        window.console.log("image trigger");
        self.showControls(this, "img");
    });
```

How can I set this up so that the user can hover over the paragraph or the image inside of it without having them effect each other?

Comment: Doesn't the user first have to hover over the paragraph before moving to hover over the image?

Comment: @Jimbo I suppose, but even so the issue remains that the second mouseenter event is not being fired when the user moves the mouse into the image.

Comment: @Matanya unfortunately that is not an option in this particular case

Comment: @Matanya Ah, I didn't think of that I will definitely keep that in mind. If you want to, please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a span to the text and latch on to it, to separate the event handlers.:

```
<p><span>Some text..</span> <img src="(URL)" /></p>
```

if you want the `img` mouseenter to also trigger the `span` event, you can call `$("span").mouseenter();` in your `img` event handler

Comment: This is the best option for this particular case, But I can't seem to find a way to wrap only the text of a paragraph with spans using jQuery.

Comment: How is the HTML generated? Can't you wrap it in the server-side?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think I can use the .text() jQuery method though to do it client side since it is only to set up the UI for the user to edit the content.

Comment: if I use html() won't I get the image tag as well?

Comment: Indeed, so that I can wrap the text in a span and then dump it back into the paragraph. Is there a better way to do it that you can think of?

Comment: I'm lacking some context. Where does the HTML come from? Where is it generated? Why can't you - server or client side - generate it as it should be, instead of replacing?

Comment: The HTML is pre-defined and it is unchangeable server side. I do not want to make a permanent change because it is intended to be used as web site content. If i can avoid adding extra tags in the markup then that would be better.

I found a way to wrap the text in span tags: $(this).contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; }).wrap("<span/>");

Comment: Great. I still find it a bit of an overkill, but then I don't know the circumstances well enough :)

Comment: Actually, even though I posted my own answer, I like this one. So I'm upvoting :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting a small delay on the mouseenter() before running whatever is in it, and require the mouse to *stay within that area* for say, a second before triggering.

Therefore if the user mouses over the paragraph before the image, they need to hover for a second to see anything for the paragraph.

---

jQuery EXAMPLE from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382722/hover-child-element-only)... You may wish to fit this to your problem.

```
$("#paragraph").hover(function() {
  $.data(this, "timer", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
     $(this).click();
  }, this), 2000));
}, function() {
   clearTimeout($.data(this, "timer"));
});
```

That looks like it's waiting two seconds before triggering an event (click in this case). Either way, this is what I would look towards coding; a delay before triggering a click on each element.